# Segmentation Fault при использовании pytest + selene + allure

Tags: python, allure

При запуске теста и генерации xml файла ( командой --alluredir "директория"), после прохождения тестов выпадает ошибка Segmentation Fault.
Папка с xml создается, но после генерации отчета в html показывает пустой отчет

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста сам код и ошибк

Comment: Код - элементарный скрипт автотестов с использованием вышеуказаных фреймворков. 
Вывод консоли после прохождения теста 
case.py .Segmentation fault: 11                                                                                 
И еще ошибка http://monosnap.com/image/6yHRTlgJCRt5ipEpTKvayfayZRtRXp